# Array based search function

Tags: c, arrays, search

I have been trying to create a search function based exclusively on arrays rather than strings. The  problem that I currently seem to be finding is that the code is tagging locations, without actually finding the correct letters. The end goal is for the code to find the full word and state how many characters it is into the line. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
int main()
{
    int read = 1, i = 0, z = 0, q, o = 0, b;
    char a[15];
    char letters [] = "HELLOMYNAMEISELDERPRICEANDIHAVECOMETOSHAREWITHYOUTHISMOSTAMAZINGBOOK";
    printf("HELLOMYNAMEISELDERPRICEANDIHAVECOMETOSHAREWITHYOUTHISMOSTAMAZINGBOOK\n");
    printf("Please type in a word to search for in upper case:\n");
    scanf(" %c", &a[1]);
    scanf("%c", &a[2]);
    if (a[2] != '\n') {scanf("%c", &a[3]); q=2;}
    if (read == 1) {if (a[3] != '\n') {scanf("%c", &a[4]); q=3;} else read = 0;}
    if (read == 1) {if (a[4] != '\n') {scanf("%c", &a[5]); q=4;} else read = 0;}
    if (read == 1) {if (a[5] != '\n') {scanf("%c", &a[6]); q=5;} else read = 0;}
    if (read == 1) {if (a[6] != '\n') {scanf("%c", &a[7]); q=6;} else read = 0;}
    if (read == 1) {if (a[7] != '\n') {scanf("%c", &a[8]); q=7;} else read = 0;}
    if (read == 1) {if (a[8] != '\n') {scanf("%c", &a[9]); q=8;} else read = 0;}
    if (read == 1) {if (a[9] != '\n') {scanf("%c", &a[10]); q=9;} else read = 0;}
    if (read == 1) {if (a[10] != '\n') {scanf("%c", &a[11]); q=10;} else read = 0;}
    if (read == 1) {if (a[11] != '\n') {scanf("%c", &a[12]); q=11;} else read = 0;}
    if (read == 1) {if (a[12] != '\n') {scanf("%c", &a[13]); q=12;} else read = 0;}
    if (read == 1) {if (a[13] != '\n') {scanf("%c", &a[14]); q=13;} else read = 0;}
    if (read == 1) {if (a[14] != '\n') {scanf("%c", &a[15]); q=14;} else read = 0;}
    while (i != 1){
        printf("line read\n");
        if (a[1] == letters[z]){
            printf("Found");
        for (int p=0; p < q; p++){
              o = z+p;
              printf("checking for word\n");
              if (a[p] == letters[o]){
                    printf("That bitch");}
              else {break;}
        }}
        z++;
        if (letters[z]=='\n'){i = 1;}
    }
    printf("%c", letters[z]);
    printf("hmmm");
}
```

Comment: Hint: All the lines stating with `if (read == 1)` can be replaced by just 2, or maybe 3 lines. I see a pattern here. Use a loop.

Comment: ooh, good point, I'll do that now

Comment: BTW a string is just an array of char terminated by a NUL characters. You're creating a problem where there isn't one.

Comment: I'm more specifically trying to do it without using string.h

Comment: So what prevents you from using `scanf("%s", a)`? Or at least write your own "ReadString" function?.

Comment: My own sheer stupidity apparently. I got confused about directories. Thank you for the help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215237/discussion-between-thomas-fraser-and-jabberwocky).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This redefined code should work for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "HELLOMYNAMEISELDERPRICEANDIHAVECOMETOSHAREWITHYOUTHISMOSTAMAZINGBOOK";
    char letter[100];
    int i, j, k, counter;

    i = j = k = counter = 0;

    printf("%s\n", str);

    printf("Enter a substring to find: ");
    scanf("%s", letter);

    for (i = 0; str[i]; i++) { // str[i] != '\0'

        if (str[i] == letter[j]) {
            for (k = i, j = 0; str[k] && letter[j]; j++, k++)
                if (str[k] != letter[j])
                    break;

            if (!letter[j]) { // when letter[j] meets false and substring found
                printf("\nFound at %d!\n", counter);
                return 0;
            }
        } else {
            printf("."); // for decoration
            counter++;
        }
    }
    printf(" No matches!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

> **Sample Output**

```
HELLOMYNAMEISELDERPRICEANDIHAVECOMETOSHAREWITHYOUTHISMOSTAMAZINGBOOK
Enter a substring to find: BOOK
................................................................
Found at 64!
```